# Why Azure allowing to create and assign custom Azure RBAC definitions despite not having Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2 license?

Tags: azure-cli, microsoft-entra-id

**Issue**: I was able to create and assign custom Azure RBAC definitions when I am not supposed to.

**Symptoms**: I was able to create and update custom Azure role definitions and assignments using **Azure CLI** commands even though I have *Microsoft Entra ID Free* license and such functionality requires Microsoft Entra ID P1 or Microsoft Entra ID P2.

**Background**:
While learning about Azure through a book, I came across a lesson where you create a role definition and assignments using Azure CLI commands such as `az role definition create` and `az role assignment create`.

When I went to see the results in Azure Portal, I was provided with the message:

> To create custom roles, your organization needs Microsoft Entra ID
> Premium P1 or P2. Start a free trial.

I was confused by this because the commands did not return errors but rather the expected successful JSON reply.

I confirmed the definitions and assignments using:

- `az role definition list` and `az role assignment list`.
- I also created a user account, and a blob in one of my storage accounts, and verified the assignment in Azure Portal as well.

Check attached screenshots.

[image: Custom Roll Assignment]
[image: Resource group reader JSON]
[image: Resource group reader JSON]
[image: Access to storage confirmed]

**Ask**: I am sure this can't be right (Unless I am missing something). If that's the case, I wasn't sure where on GitHub I need to report such a problem or if a Microsoft representative would take that forward from here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just useless noise. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know its content. The title as written now says absolutely nothing meaningful. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Comment: this is the expected behavior, roles for resources are different from MS Entra roles.

Comment: @KenWhite. Your comment is honestly rude and inaccurate the least. All I had to edit in my original post was adding a single word "Azure" before every mention of "RBAC". So, I didn't need to see "How to Ask", the question was well constructed. And it wasn't "useless noise" or "says absolutely meaningful".

Comment: My comment was based on your initial title, which was **Potential issue**, which you can clearly see in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77544973/revisions).  There was nothing rude or inaccurate - those two words as the entire title are just useless noise. After your edit, the title is fine, because it actually says something meaningful, but you made that edit **after my comment was posted**. But my first comment was entirely accurate and in no way rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, custom RBAC roles are **different** from custom directory roles.
>
> Custom RBAC roles are for managing **Azure resources** under subscription whereas custom directory roles are for managing **Azure AD**(Microsoft Entra) resources like users, groups, applications etc... at tenant level.

Having either **Owner** or **User Access Administrator** role is enough to create custom RBAC definitions, that does not require any *Premium P1 or P2* licenses.

I created custom RBAC definition named **"Custom Resource Group Reader"** and able to fetch its role definition like this:

```
az role definition list --name "Custom Resource Group Reader"
```

**Response:**

[image]

> You need *Microsoft Entra ID Premium P1 or P2* licenses for creating
> **custom directory** roles, not custom RBAC definitions.

When I tried to create **custom directory** role with *Microsoft Entra ID Free* license, I got same message as you in Portal like this:

[image]

After acquiring *Microsoft Entra ID Premium P2* license, I'm able to create **custom directory** role successfully as below:

[image]

**References:**

[Create custom roles in Microsoft Entra role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-create)

[Azure custom roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)

Comment: Thank you. That was it. The requirement is only for Entra ID roles not Azure roles.